# Adding opengl support on vm(vmware,azure) to run Go Fyne app

Tags: azure, go, opengl, virtual-machine, fyne

I am trying to run a Fyne app on a VM. I have attempted it on VirtualBox and Azure. After running the app, I get the following error:

```
  Cause:APIUnavailable: WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL
  At: fyne.io/fyne/v2@v2.2.3/internal/driver/glfw/driver.go:148
```

[image]

I was able to solve this in VM by enabling **3D acceleration**. But I am not able to do the same in Azure.

[image]

One option is to select the template which supports GPU. There are special VM series like the N-series VMs which support GPU. But just to run a Fyne app, I don't want to pay for a GPU VM.

Another option is to use the GPU pass-through feature. But I am not able to find any documentation on how to do this.

Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the **opengl32.dll** file from [here](https://fdossena.com/?p=mesa/index.frag), under "Solution 2: If you're on Windows 7/8"
2. Go to **C:\Windows\System32** and find **opengl32.dll**, right click and go to properties -> security -> Advanced, a new window will open
3. Select **change**, a new window will open. In the **Enter the object name to select** section, enter the user name (Sanjay) and **check names**

- Follow the [Blog](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/you-require-permission-from-trustedinstaller-error-fixing-guide/) or [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zi8n6wYBsWs) to change the properties of the dll file

  Note: If properties are not changed you will get the "you require permission from trustedinstaller" error

5. Now backup the original dll file and replace it with the downloaded one.
6. Now Simply start the "Fyne" app and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Running a Fyne app on a desktop screen requires OpenGL, this is unavoidable. As you have found most VMs call this “3D acceleration”.
Without this support it cannot draw to the window.

Comment: yes, I am aware of that, but how can I achieve that in Azure VM? Is there a way to install supported OpenGL in azure?

Comment: Oh I’m sorry, I don’t know Azure details - I hadn’t realised that was what the question was for.